# « He reconnoitred the ground personally [...] » : reconnaître, faire (la/une) reconnaissance de ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, comparaison-de-langues, absence-d-article

On a un sens du verbe [*reconnaître*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/reconna%C3%AEtre) en défense pour « effectuer une [reconnaissance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/reconnaissance) sur le terrain pour repérer les lieux, observer la position de l'ennemi »(TLFi) ; dans le domaine maritime pour un sens similaire on dit que ce serait synonyme d'« effectuer la reconnaissance de »(TLFi). On a des traductions d'une citation<sup>1</sup> en langue anglaise employant le verbe [*reconnoitre*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=reconnoitre) :

> [Il fait personnellement une reconnaissance du terrain](http://www.cmp-cpm.forces.gc.ca/dhh-dhp/gal/vcg-gcv/bio/brillant-j-fra.asp) [...]
>   [Il fit personnellement une reconnaissance du terrain](http://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.r22er.com%2Fpages%2Fheritage%2FHistoire%2FCroix_victoria%2Fbrillant.html) [...]
>  Il fit personnellement la reconnaissance du terrain [...]
>   [Il reconnut lui-même le terrain](http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/fra/decouvrez/patrimoine-militaire/premiere-guerre-mondiale/100-histoires/Pages/brillant.aspx) [...]
>  Il fit lui-même
>   reconnaissance du terrain [...]

Pourquoi trouverait-on une tournure plus claire/usuelle pour traduire ou pour exprimer l'action ?

- Avec le complément *du terrain*, l'emploi en défense et le contexte/style de la citation, quelle nuance introduirait l'emploi d'un article défini (*la
  reconnaissance*) dans la phrase ?
- L'ellipse de l'article (*faire reconnaissance de*) est-elle concevable
  (comme avec [*faire connaissance de*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4315)) ; est-ce d'un registre différent ?
- Le fait que le verbe *reconnaître* soit bien usuel en français le
  rend-il moins apte à exprimer l'action de *faire une/la
  reconnaissance* dans la citation ?

---

> <sup>1</sup> Lt. John Brillant, M.C., late Quebec R. — For most
>   conspicuous bravery and outstanding devotion to duty when in charge of
>   a company which he led in attack during two days with absolute fearlessness and extraordinary ability and initiative, the extent of
>   the advance being twelve miles. On the first day of operations shortly
>   after the attack had begun, his company's left flank was held up by an
>   enemy machine gun. Lt. Brillant rushed and captured the machine-gun,
>   personally killing two of the enemy crew. Whilst doing this, he was
>   wounded but refused to leave his command. Later on the same day, his
>   company was held up by heavy machine-gun fire. He **reconnoitred** the
>   ground personally, organised a party of two platoons and rushed
>   straight for the machine-gun nest. Here 150 enemy and fifteen
>   machine-guns were captured. Lt. Brillant personally killing five of
>   the enemy, and being wounded a second time. He had this wound dressed
>   immediately, and again refused to leave his company. Subsequently this
>   gallant officer detected a field gun firing on his men over open
>   sights. He immediately organised and led a “ rushing ” party towards the
>   gun. After progressing about 600 yards, he was again seriously
>   wounded. In spite of this third wound, he continued to advance for
>   some 200 yards more, when he fell unconscious from exhaustion and loss
>   of blood. Lt. Brillant's wonderful example throughout the day inspired
>   his men with an enthusiasm and dash which largely contributed towards
>   the success of the operations.
>
> [ Texte en format condensé du [*Fourth Supplement to The London Gazette*](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/30922/supplement/11429) du
>   mardi, le 24 septembre  1918, décernant la [*Croix de Victoria*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croix_de_Victoria)
>   (Victoria Cross) à différents officiers, dont le lieutenant [Jean Brillant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Brillant) VC,
>   [MC](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/30901/supplement/11039) (1890-1918 : [Villers-Bretonneux](https://www.cwgc.org/find-war-dead/casualty/575645/BRILLANT,%20JOHN)). ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La formule/collocation consacrée est *partir en reconnaissance*. Je ne sais pas si l'usage de *reconnaître* seul pour cette cette expression est commun dans le langage militaire (auquel cas ce serait acceptable), mais ce n'est certainement pas un usage du langage courant.

En l'occurrence, je croit que la formulation *il fit lui même **la** reconnaissance du terrain* serait la plus naturelle.

Comment: Merci ! Est-ce que partir en reconnaissance prend le complément prép. _du terrain_ ; le TLFi dit sur/jusqu'à avec _pousser_ ? N'hésitez pas à présenter le bout de phrase ainsi remanié (partit personnellement en reconnaissance du terrain ??) dans votre réponse...

Comment: Non, ces complément sont optionnels, mais il est vrai que *reconnaître le terrain* est probablement plus commun que *reconnaître* seul. En général, une reconnaissance se fait dans le cadre d'un mouvement de troupe planifié, et les intervenants sont tous bien au courant d'où elle s'effectue, donc ce détail n'est pas obligatoire.